# SQL Server getting arithmetic overflow error converting vachar to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We are working on the mapping project, in this project first we need to import a `.csv` file, after then this data will be imported into the table, we have some external predefined column in temporary table, with this column we need to mapped data with the CSV imported data, we have done this functionality, but while saving mapped data for some scenario we are getting a SQL error:

> Numeric value out of range,arithmatic overflow error, converting varchar to data type numeric

We are executing this query:

```
INSERT INTO SD_Trey_Sams ([PharmacyTotalClaimAmt], [PharmacyMiscFee]) 
    SELECT   
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), LEFT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', '')), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid),'\','')), 8000) + 'X') -1)) AS [TRIM(PatientPaid)] 
    FROM 
        file_598071306a1b4
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue? I want to insert all the data which is exist in the `file_598071306a1b4` table, this table will contain CSV data, this data can be whatever

Comment: Well, what does your data in the `.csv` file look like??

Comment: i believe that your DECIMAL(12,2) is the reason try a bigger decimal point

Comment: @marc_s, CSV has around 2.5 lakh records, so it's difficult to say about the data, it has price like $53434.50 something like that, it can be string also, so i removed non numeric data

Comment: @RAHULSR, can you please tell me what should i have to do for it ?

Comment: Well, in that case: try to select from your data, and just display the **string** that you're eventually trying to convert to `decimal(12,2)`. Are any of those strings longer than 13 characters (12 digits and a decimal point)? ---> Those will cause trouble. Are any of the strings *longer* than 10 digits *before* the decimal point? --> those will cause trouble

Comment: @marc_s so there is no solution for it ?

Comment: I just told you how to debug this problem - that **is** the solution ..... there is no magic "tell me what's wrong" way of solving this - sorry, it *will* require some work on your part...

Comment: There are lots of string which size in longer than 13

Comment: In SQL Server **2012** and newer, you *could* use `TRY_CONVERT` to try and convert a string to a given datatype; if this fails, it'll return `NULL` - but that's not available in SQL Server 2008 unfortunately....

Comment: @marc_s can you please tell me which conversion works with that ?

Comment: @marc_s , thanks, i resolved the issue by TRY_CONVERT function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Find the offending value.  My first thought would be:

```
SELECT   
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 10), LEFT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', '')), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid),'\','')), 8000) + 'X') -1)) AS val 
FROM file_598071306a1b4
ORDER BY val DESC;
```

Of course, that might still overflow, so you could just focus on the length:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 10), LEFT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', '')), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid),'\','')), 8000) + 'X') -1)) AS val 
      FROM file_598071306a1b4
     ) t
ORDER BY LEN(val) DESC;
```

And, if you are content getting `NULL` values when the conversion does not work, then use `TRY_CONVERT()` instead.  So, this might be the easiest way to investigate:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT PatientPaid,
             TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 10), LEFT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', '')), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid), '\', ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', REPLACE(TRIM(PatientPaid),'\','')), 8000) + 'X') -1)) AS val 
      FROM file_598071306a1b4
     ) t
WHERE val IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, i resolved the issue by TRY_CONVERT function

Answer (score 0):

@NikulPanchal without knowing what is your input we can say a little but know this there are many things you need to take in consideration

1. Your input string, increase the size like (18, 6) or as much as your input string requires
2. Also since you are inserting into another table let me tell you that if your column size is less than the input then it will be automatically trimmed...

PS: wanted to put in as comment and not as answer but it's too long

Comment: @marc_s inreasing the variables size does